# Unable to update a list with react when its value is being changed using the hook useState function from React TypeError: map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, map-function

I want to get a list of values updated whenever its value is changed through a hook setState function, however I am getting an error I don't know why... I am getting a .map is not a function TypeError

Down bellow is my code and I also have a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-satoshi-zjbpg?file=/src/Incomes.js:23-1551

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const fetchInvestment = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "https://6r3yk.sse.codesandbox.io/api/investments/60b2696de8be014bac79a2a1"
  );
  return res.data.invest.incomes;
};

export default function Incomes() {
  const [incomes, setIncomes] = useState([]);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(undefined);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInvestments = async () => {
      const res = await fetchInvestment();
      setIncomes(res);
    };
    if (incomes.length === 0) {
      getInvestments();
    }
    console.log(incomes);
  }, [incomes]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input
        id="monthEl"
        type="month"
        value={date}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setDate(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <input
        id="monthEl"
        type="number"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const income = {};
          income[date] = Number(value);
          setIncomes(incomes.push(income));
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(incomes);
          }, 2000);
        }}
      >
        Save
      </button>
      <ul>
        {incomes.map((income) => (
          <li key={Object.keys(income)}>
            {Object.keys(income)}: {Object.values(income)}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Promise is pending or data is object not a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```js
setIncomes(incomes.push(income));
```

With this

```js
setIncomes([...incomes, income]);
```

The `.push` method returns the length of the array, not the actual array. You can use the spread operator to spread the current array and then add on the new item to the end of it.

Doing this should also work:

```js
incomes.push(incomes)
setIncomes(incomes)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're getting that error because the data coming back from your API isn't an array. Judging by your code, I'm guessing you're expecting a key/value map, which in JS is an object. You might be able to use `Object.keys(incomes).map(...)`, but without knowing the specific response format, I can't say for sure.

There are 2 other issues with your code:

First, you can't `push` onto `incomes` because it's a React state array. Instead, you need to use the `setIncomes` callback...

```
setIncomes([...incomes, income])
```

Additionally, the way you're using `Object.keys` and `Object.values` is not correct. Again, can't say what the correct way is without knowing specifics of your response format.